# Constructing a Stage object in javafx throws unknown errors

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

My programming class recently "covered" java gui through javafx. I didn't understand half of it because due to being forced online and losing a week due to COVID, the teacher rushed through it and had us just copy the code she was doing with almost no explanation. I am trying to learn more on my own because I would like to be able to give my programs a basic GUI instead of a console command line, but when I try to construct a new Stage object, I get errors I haven't seen before. Here is my code.

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stage window = new Stage();
    }
}
```

I do not know why this is causing an issue since I am literally only initializing an object.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1451)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:256)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:244)
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:445)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:369)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:680)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:74)
    ... 4 more
```

I tried splitting the declaration and initialization, and the error occurs in the initialization of the object. I also tried moving "Stage stage1 = new Stage();" into a separate class where it could be in a non-static method and calling it from there, but as expected that didn't work either.

Searching for the error, I found this page https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification/issues/8
where someone using different parts of javafx had what sounded like the same issue. The solution suggested would be to in my case move the javafx part of the program to a javafx thread, but I don't know how to do that or what it actually means. I'm not sure what else to do with it so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't create the `Stage` in `main`. Follow the standard pattern for starting your FX Application: e.g. see the [`Application` docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html).

Comment: I placed it in a start() method when I tried calling it as part of another class, I got the same error. I'll read that though in case you mean something I'm missing

Comment: You're not supposed to call `start()` yourself. It's called for you as part of the `Application` startup process. I'm pretty sure your instructor didn't instantiate `Stage` in the `main` method. Any JavaFX documentation whatsoever will show you how to do this, e.g. see https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java

Comment: Ok the example in there is very helpful, I didn't really know any of this about implementing it as an Application and overloading the start method correctly. And yeah they didn't, which was confusing to me because they never said why but now I know

Comment: **Always read the documentation.** E.g. you knew the error came from the `Stage` class, so the first thing you should look at is the [documentation for that class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html). The constructor documentation there explicitly tells you it throws the exception you saw if you call the constructor from the wrong thread, and it also has a complete example of how to launch a JavaFX application.

Comment: James_D if you want to put what you said in your comments as an answer I'll choose it so the question gets closed

Answer (score 0):

The comment from James_D pretty much answers the question, and I'm quoting it here so the post has a formal answer:

"You're not supposed to call `start()` yourself. It's called for you as part of the Application startup process. I'm pretty sure your instructor didn't instantiate Stage in the main method. Any JavaFX documentation whatsoever will show you how to do this, e.g. see [https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java"](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java%22).

Due to my inexperience at the time particularly in regards to threads, coupled with COVID largely rendering the rest of that semester obsolete when it came to learning, I did not know that `start()` is a pre-implemented method that is run on the Application thread, rather than the Main thread. Creating the class for the Stage which extends Application and is called from Main to start running the Application solves the issue.